# how to group columns efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10000 columns and the column name is just the numerical data like depth, for each column is for each depth. I'd like to group the columns from 10000 column into 5000 columns by increasing spacing between each column. I am not sure how to do it.

Here is a simple example for demonstration:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,3,4],'2.1':[2,4,6,8],'3.2':[3,6,9,12],'4.3':[4,8,12,16]})
df

1   2.5 3.2 4.3
0   1   2   3   4
1   2   4   6   8
2   3   6   9   12
3   4   8   12  16

df.columns=df.columns.astype('float')
depth_list=df.columns.tolist()
import numpy as np
spacing_new=2
depth_list_grouped=[ x for x in np.arange(depth_list[0],depth_list[-1],step=spacing_new)]
depth_list_grouped
[1.0, 3.0]
```

Now I'd like to group column using the above new grouped depth of [1,3], for grouped columns of 1 is equal to mean value of original column of 1,2, grouped column of 3 is equal to mean value of original column of 2,3, 4.

Here is my code which is very tedious and take a long time to do for 10000 columns:

```
df_grouped=pd.DataFrame()
for col_new in depth_list_grouped:
    df_grouped[col_new]=[0]*len(df)
    count=0
    for col in df.columns:
        if (col>=col_new-spacing_new/2)&((col<=col_new+spacing_new/2)):
            df_grouped[col_new]+=df[col]
            count+=1
    df_grouped[col_new]=df_grouped[col_new]/count    

df_grouped

1   3
0   1.5 3.0
1   3.0 6.0
2   4.5 9.0
3   6.0 12.0
```

Any better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "groups" are not exclusive, you can try with a single `for` loop:

```
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame()
for col_new in depth_list_grouped:
    df_grouped[col_new] = df.loc[:,max(df.columns.min(),col_new-spacing_new//2):min(col_new+spacing_new//2,df.columns.max())].mean(axis=1)

>>> df_grouped
     1     3
0  1.5   3.0
1  3.0   6.0
2  4.5   9.0
3  6.0  12.0
```

Edit: With `rolling`, you can just find the average of every 3 columns and then keep only the ones you need:

```
df_grouped = df.T.rolling(spacing_new+1,min_periods=1).mean().shift(-1).T[depth_list_grouped]
```

Note: I have used the double transpose to avoid `rolling` along`axis=1` which will be removed in a future version.

Comment: wow, that work, thanks not_special, I appreciate it. However I do got a lot of warning like this:  PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df_grouped[col_new] = df.loc[:,max(df.columns.min(),col_new-spacing_new//2):min(col_new+spacing_new//2,df.columns.max())].mean(axis=1)

Comment: @roudan - See the edit to use `pd.concat` in a single-line solution :)

Comment: Hi the new code didn't work, the old code takes less than one minute for my big dataframe, however new codes are taking forever. Do you know what is the issue for new code? Thanks

Comment: @roudan: It gives me the exact same output as the old code. Unsure why it isn't working for you. The first `for` loop is MUCH faster however, so maybe you should just use that. I changed the `concat` version to use `rolling` instead.

Comment: Hi for above simple case it work, but not working for other general case. The reason is the depth_list_grouped is not in the index.  For example, if original dataframe has random column values, then it is not working. I think we need to find the  matching index between new column and old column.

Comment: Ah yes, you would need to provide more representative data in that case. You mentioned "column name is just the numerical data" so I presumed it's sequential.

Comment: sorry for confusing. no, the column name is random floating numerical values. any alternative solution? Thanks

Comment: You'll have to provide a better example then. `rolling` should still work with some modifications.

Comment: yes I just updated my example by adding decimal to column values, thanks for helping, I appreicate it

Comment: The `depth_list_grouped` has columns that are not in your dataframe. What should your output be? Can't you just round down the column names to integers and use my code?